# Using Version info in msbuild and ClickOnce

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce

I have a msbuild script used for automating ClickOnce installation. While trying to add version info to the publish directory I get an error when trying to build a path string using that version.

```
<Target Name="GetVersion">
   <Message Text="Getting version info..."/>
   <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="@(GetVersionAssembly)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies"
              ItemName="GetVersionAssemblyInfo"/>
   </GetAssemblyIdentity>
   <Message Text="%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)..."/>
</Target>

<Target Name="CopyFilesToVirtualRoot" DependsOnTargets="PrepareClickOnceDeployment;DeleteVirtualRootFiles;GetVersion">
   <Message Text="Copying files to $(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)..."/>
   <Copy  SourceFiles="@(ClickOnceInstallationFiles)"
         DestinationFiles="@(ClickOnceInstallationFiles->'$(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
   <Copy  SourceFiles="@(AppManifestContents)"
           DestinationFiles="@(AppManifestContents->'$(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)\Application Files\Version_%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension).deploy')"/>
</Target>
```

When running I get the following error

```
error MSB4043: The item metadata reference "%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)" is invalid
because it is qualified with an item name. Item metadata referenced in transforms do not 
need to be qualified, because the item name is automatically deduced from the items being
transformed. Change "%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)" to "%(Version)".
```

If I change it to %(Version) all I get is a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using target batching so MSBuild runs the `CopyFilesToVirtualRoot` target once per assembly version. Then you can stuff the version into a property and reference that in your item transform.

```
<Target Name="CopyFilesToVirtualRoot"
    DependsOnTargets="PrepareClickOnceDeployment;DeleteVirtualRootFiles;GetVersion"
    Outputs="%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AppVersion>%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)</AppVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Copying files to $(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)..."/>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(ClickOnceInstallationFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(ClickOnceInstallationFiles->'$(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(AppManifestContents)"
        DestinationFiles="@(AppManifestContents->'$(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)\Application Files\Version_$(AppVersion)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension).deploy')"/>
</Target>
```

I guess this is weird because if any of your assemblies have different versions, you will have multiple copies of the manifest contents.

That said, you could just create a property from with the item meta data.

```
<Target Name="CopyFilesToVirtualRoot"
    DependsOnTargets="PrepareClickOnceDeployment;DeleteVirtualRootFiles;GetVersion"
    Outputs="%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)">
    <CreateProperty
        Value="%(GetVersionAssemblyInfo.Version)">
        <Output PropertyName="AppVersion" TaskParameter="Value" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <Message Text="Copying files to $(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)..."/>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(ClickOnceInstallationFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(ClickOnceInstallationFiles->'$(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(AppManifestContents)"
        DestinationFiles="@(AppManifestContents->'$(ClickOnceVirtualRootDir)\Application Files\Version_$(AppVersion)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension).deploy')"/>
</Target>
```

I think either will get you what you need.